# Modal dialog always misses first button tap after opening from double tap

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog

I am displaying a modal dialog when the user double taps inside a TextBlock. Its a backdoor to a hidden settings panel. The TextBlock is contained in a Popup. I am finding that it is always necessary to tap/touch once before any of the buttons in the dialog do anything. Kind of annoying. Initially was using MouseLeftButtonDown and ClickCount==2 on the TextBlock but have also tried the DoubleClickEvent of a Label and their Preview... versions. Nothing I have tried fixes this problem.

```
       <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="16" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,10,0,10">
            <Run Text="{x:Static languages:Strings.SoftwareVersion}"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding SoftwareBuild}"/>
            <Run Text="      "/>
            <Run Text="{x:Static languages:Strings.FirmwareVersion}"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding FirmwareBuild}"/>
        </TextBlock>

        private void TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.ClickCount == 2)
                {
                    var sw = new SettingsWindow();
                    sw.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
                    sw.DataContext = this.DataContext;
                    sw.ShowDialog();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.HandleException();
            }
        }
```

I've made a correction to the title as the problem is only with touch/tap behaviour; the first mouse click does get through only the first touch fails.

Added more code for the SettingsWindow as requested:-

```
<Window x:Class="XXXXXXX.UserInterface.Views.Miscellaneous.SettingsWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="SettingsWindow" Height="150" Width="200">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Click Me" Click="Button_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="48" Margin="50,30,37,41" Width="105" />
    </Grid>
</Window>

    public partial class SettingsWindow : Window
    {
        public SettingsWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as Button).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            (sender as Button).Content = "WAS CLICKED";
        }
    }
```

Ive tried focus setting in the load and activate event of the dialog to no avail. Even tried raising a MouseClick event using RaiseEvent.

Same problem if I only count 1 click too but with 1 click the problem goes away if I count MouseButtonUp events not MouseButtonDown, but then I lose the ClickCount==2 option which doesnt work at all. Somewhere a MouseButtonUp event is getting lost.

So I'm about to manage my own double clicking to get this to work ...

but suggestions welcome as to why this breaks.

Jerry

Comment: Where are the buttons in your example?

Comment: Try setting the owner for the dialog, that might help. You would want to do that anyway.

Comment: @mm8 have added the button code.@Jim tried that but it didn't help.

Comment: Please can be more specific? I am confused by your explanations.  Double click is working but not double tap? And what about the buttons? What do they have to do with this? Can you please show the complete dialog (at least the `Popup` and the buttons)? There is a `Popup` inside the dialog?

Comment: @BionicCode yes you're right so i've edited the title changing click to tap. I don't think the Popup is important.The essence of the problem is I do a double tap to open a modal dialog SettingsWindow. However the first tap of a button in SettingsWindow has no effect but works second time.

Comment: Hey @Jerry, I am pretty sure it is all about the `Popup`. You can test it if you move the `TextBox` out of the `Popup`. Tap should then behave as expected. Let me know if this solves the issue. I will then explain the issue and provide a proper solution.

Comment: @BionicCode, I can reproduce the problem without a Popup, just using a MainWindow/TextBlock and the SettingsWindow/Button.

Comment: I see. Have you tried to handle the `UIElement.TouchDowm` or Preview...? It might be because of the way WPF handles touch. A touch input first raises touch events (`TouchDown` and `TouchUp`). They first traverse the visual tree as tunneling events and if not handled, as bubbling events. If you don't handle the touch events during traversal, they are transformed in to a click event and will traverse the tree once more.You should handle the original touch events in addition to the click events. Don't forget to mark the touch event as handled to prevent it from triggering a click event handler.

Comment: Maybe I can find the MSDN resouce where I once read about it when I had to deal with it too.

Comment: [Touch Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/input-overview#touch-events). I think you should handle touch up event (tunneling or bubbling). Read the remarks of the docs when handling TouchDown. Couldn't find the article that was on my mind.

Comment: I worked around this in the end by using the TextBlock.MouseLeftButtonUp event instead and using a stopwatch to determine if its a double click/tap. I found that the ClickCount property in the Up event didn't really work to detect double clicks but the stopwatch works fine and all buttons click first time in the dialog box. I generally try to avoid adding touch specific code unless absolutely necessary.